# WSO2 Micro integrator proxy service url

Tags: wso2-micro-integrator, wso2-esb

Working with an extremely simple proxy service configured on the new 1.0.0 Micro Integrator by WSO2. I use the Integration Studio and it's buildin intergator to run and test the functionality. It seems however that for some reason I cannot call my proxy service.

I can clearly see my changes are reflected as it boots up and the following line appears:

> ProxyService named 'myprox' has been deployed from file

Also, it mentions that the endpoints have been configured:

> INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.core.PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager} - Pass-through EI_INTERNAL_HTTP_INBOUND_ENDPOINT Listener started on 0.0.0.0:9201

The custom proxy service is now narrowed down to just a LOG and RESPOND mediator. Whatever URL I use, the same error keeps popping up:

> WARN {org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.internal.http.api.InternalAPIDispatcher} - No Internal API found to dispatch the message

So far I have tried every type of combination I can imagine, with every one of them providing above message. The latest I tried was:

> http://localhost:9201/services/myprox

I tried with and without the "/services/" subdirectory. I tried with and without HTTPS using the provided 9164 port. I also tried the variations of the 8290 and 8253 ports to no avail.

When I run this CAR file with EI 6.5.0. I can get result on the url mentioned above.

What is going on here?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that I get this when running the micro integrator in 3 different ways; via docker, via the integration studio and standalone commandline.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to call the inbound endpoint port for a proxy. The WARN message you have shown indicates that. In micro integrator the default port for proxy services is 8290. So your proxy URL should look like below.

http://localhost:8290/services/myprox

(Please note that the above mentioned port is the default one. It might change, if you started have the server with a port offset or configured differently in your settings.)

Please go through this blog for a proxy sample created and deployed into Micro Integrator from Integration Studio.

https://www.yenlo.com/blog/a-first-look-at-wso2-enterprise-integrator-6.5.0-m5-micro-integrator-and-developer-studio

Comment: Hi Arunan. Thanks for your answer. The location you mentioned I already tried as well. See my original answer. I will look through the blog just to be sure but I don't think it might solve this issue for me. Will keep this issue updated.

Comment: As I mentioned, check the ports as well.

Comment: As I mentioned in my original answer: " I also tried the variations of the 8290 and 8253 ports to no avail."

Comment: Can you confirm whether you got any log like below

INFO {org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.http.management.HTTPEndpointManager} - Listener is already started for port : 8000

Comment: Negative. I know what ports are open and closed, but especially because I have tried to get this working on 3 different ways (local, docker and via Integration studio's built-in). The only ones opened are the ones I mentioned in my opening post (i.e.: 9201, 9164, 8290 and 8253).